# Using intel graphics with nvidia drivers boot loop

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have built in intel graphics that I want to use for my display, and keep my nvidia card for non-graphics workloads. After installing nvidia drivers (384.90), I get a boot loop after trying to log in. My monitor is plugged into the intel graphics output.

This is on a desktop with a PCIx nvidia graphics card.

syslog shows

```
Sep 29 15:17:04 machine org.a11y.atspi.Registry[4934]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Sep 29 15:17:04 machine gnome-session[4924]: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Sep 29 15:17:04 machine gnome-session[4924]: gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
Sep 29 15:17:04 machine gnome-session[4924]: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Sep 29 15:17:04 machine gnome-session[4924]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
Sep 29 15:17:04 machine gnome-session[4924]: gnome-session-binary[4924]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Sep 29 15:17:04 machine gnome-session-binary[4924]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Sep 29 15:17:04 machine dbus[826]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Sep 29 15:17:04 machine org.gnome.ScreenSaver[4797]: ** (gnome-screensaver:5024): WARNING **: Unable to get session bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-TNOEfmxdTg: Connection refused
Sep 29 15:17:04 machine org.gnome.ScreenSaver[4797]: ** (gnome-screensaver:5024): WARNING **: Failed to register with the message bus
Sep 29 15:17:04 machine lightdm[942]: ** (lightdm:942): CRITICAL **: session_get_login1_session_id: assertion 'session != NULL' failed
Sep 29 15:17:05 machine systemd[1]: Started Session c16 of user lightdm.
Sep 29 15:17:05 machine org.a11y.atspi.Registry[5069]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. download and install nvidia drivers
2. install drivers

   - press `ctrl`  + `alt` + `F2`
   - log in
   - `sudo systemctl stop lightdm.service`
   - `chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64*`
   - blacklist nouveau driver
   - `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
   - append the following

     `blacklist lbm-nouveau
     options nouveau modeset=0
     alias nouveau off
     alias lbm-nouveau off`
   - `sudo update-initramfs -u`
   - reboot computer
   - install nvidia driver
   - press `ctrl`  + `alt` + `F2`
   - `sudo systemctl stop lightdm.service`
   - `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-* --dkms --no-opengl-files`
   - don't update your x config file when prompted
3. install m4

   - `sudo apt-get install m4`
4. download corresponding nvidia-modprobe from

   - http://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/nvidia-modprobe/
5. extract, compile, and install nvidia-modprobe

   - `tar -xvf nvidia-modprobe-*`
   - `cd nvidia-modprobe-*`
   - `make all`
   - `sudo make install`
6. reboot computer

[How to configure igpu for xserver and nvidia gpu for cuda?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779530/how-to-configure-igpu-for-xserver-and-nvidia-gpu-for-cuda)