# Nvidia drivers override AMD APU drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, amd-graphics, switchable-graphics

## In short:

Nvidia drivers take control of the graphics and my computer doesn't use the iGPU

### Here is my setup:

CPU: Ryzen 3 2200G (display)
GPU1: Gigabyte GeForce 1060 OC 3Gb, in the PCIe slot 
MB: MSI B450M Bazooka

Ubuntu 20.04, updated 06/05/2021 for the last time with private software enabled.
Display is connected to MB with HDMI, iGPU is forced in BIOS with 2GB of VRAM.

### What im trying to do:

My goal is to use the AMD APU to handle the graphics of the computer (Open source drivers, privative, i dont care as long as the graphic load is only here) and the Nvidia GPU for Cuda computing with overclocking and undervolt. For this i need to get nvidia-settings to work (i think), this is dependent on the xorg.config file because of the "coolbits" option.

### My issue(s):

Simply: every time i install the Nvidia drivers they override everything else and take the job of handling graphics. This allows me to use it an compute in it (overclock, unvervolt, everything), but slows down a lot the computer and reduces the computing power.

Also, Im a noob.

### My biggest progress so far:

1. Fresh install with only the APU installed, updated and running.
2. Shutdown system, install GPU and during startup force the iGPU to run in the BIOS (i do this first but i do check every time because this machine is making me crazy).
3. Then install Nvidia drivers with the additional drivers menu.
4. After rebooting i can access nvidia-settings, prime and nvidia-smi, but the last one shows that is running everything (just what i dont want); in this state i can run CUDA programs but not so fast. If in prime profiles i choose Energy Saving Mode (Intel) and do a reboot, i get to use the AMD APU for graphics, but the nvidia-smi, nvidia-settings and no CURA program does work, they doesn't detect it.
5. The next thing i tried is the xorg.config bit in [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/alexlee-gk/76a409f62a53883971a18a11af93241b), the difference is that i did not put any info about my iGPU because for what i see, this only apply to Intel and Nvidia GPU. Even if i put those lines (but with my amd device and its BusID) the output is the same: after restarting i get trapped in a loop in the login screen, meaning that xorg is broken. I also tried to input the IGPU data that *lspci* give to me, but the results was the same

### What i already tried:

Im going to list a few post i being trying to follow to fix this.

1. [This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779530/how-to-configure-igpu-for-xserver-and-nvidia-gpu-for-cuda)
2. [Yes, my friend, drivers do interfere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061551/how-to-configure-igpu-for-xserver-and-nvidia-gpu-for-cuda-work)
3. [And this one](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/solved-run-cuda-on-dedicated-nvidia-gpu-while-connectAnd%20this%20oneing-monitors-to-intel-hd-graphics-is-this-possible/47690/6), but doesn't solve my problem as i need to restart between changes and, you know, just changes the GPU used at that time.

I have seen a few post very similar to this but they are all oriented to INTEL HD graphics, that seem to handle X11 by default. I dont think this is the case with AMD, or at least they dont create an xorg.conf file i could use.

For me, the preferred option is to have the ability to do OC and UV with the Nvidia drivers (i understand that, for this, i need to give a few MB for the X-server so i can use the xorg.config) while using the APU for everything else. With so many laptops with similar configuration, why do they make it so hard to switch between graphics?? I understand that maybe a desktop with this devices is kinda weird, but hybrid laptops are more popular every day and they use a lot this configuration... why is so hard to make use of all the processing power??

P.D: thank you in advance and sorry for all the talking, but after almost 24h of error after error y needed to vent a little. Have a very nice day and i hope you could help me!!!!

BYeeeee