# Use integrated gpu for desktop and dedicated gpu for gaming

Tags: graphics

I just started using Ubuntu 22.04 few months ago and I'm very new to this.

I want to check if it is possible to use the Intel integrated graphics for desktop use, and my dedicated R9 380 GPU for gaming? The reason for this is my DGPU only has 2 GB VRAM and will always run with extreme frame drops (<10 fps) for games that normally would run on Windows.

I googled and somewhat found a solution by following this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779530/how-to-configure-igpu-for-xserver-and-nvidia-gpu-for-cuda). I did the fix by editing the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file as follows:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "layout"
    Screen      0  "intel" 0 0
    Screen      1  "amdgpu" 3000 0

Section "Device"
    Identifier      "intel"
    Driver          "intel"
    BusId           "PCI:0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "amdgpu"
    Driver      "amdgpu"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "intel"
    Device          "intel"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amdgpu"
    Device     "amdgpu"
    Option     "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "true"
EndSection
```

I am now able to run the games with same/better performance than I did with Windows, but I believe this workaround caused a few side effects.

The current issues are distorted window capture using OBS and Ubuntu is no longer able to login through Xorg.

Xorg login screen:

[image: Xorg login screen]

Additionally the output for `inxi -G` shows `Display: wayland server: X.Org`. Is this correct?

Comment: *which* instructions from the linked post did you follow? There are many instructions there, some of which distinctly don't work.

Comment: also what does "no longer able to login through xorg" mean? errors, something else?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I did the "fix" by editing the /etc/X11/xorg.conf. I have edited my original post above to reflect the specific fix and what I meant by logging in through ubuntu xorg. Every time I tried to log in through xorg, the screen will loop back into the login.